# Second Hand MacBook Pro has speaker's name in another language

Tags: settings, language

I just bought a second hand MacBook Pro. Everything looks clean, but the name of the Audio devices are in Japanese.
Example where this happens :

[image]

[image]

Any idea what to do to have everything in English, including the speakers and microphone's names?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Has it been properly wiped? Did you have to set it up as a brand new Mac when you first got it? See [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) which the previous owner should have done before shipping. If not, start from step 8.

Answer (score 1):

So I was actually able to fix this by setting a new primary language (French
) then restarting the laptop then switching again to English. Now the names of the audio devices are both in English.